# How can I prove the following recursive problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

While I am studying about recursive least square algorithm, I do not understand the following. The professor wrote $
\mathbf{c}_k = \mathbf{c}_{k-1} + \frac{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k e_k^*}{\lambda + {\mathbf{r}}_k^H \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k}.
$ However, I cannot understand why it becomes to that. So, I tried to prove that, but failed. Please let me know some direction. Thank you.

---

Capital bold alphabet = matrix, bold alphabet = vector, and unbold alphabet = scalar.

Given:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}_k &= \lambda^{-1}\left( \mathbf{P}_{k-1} - \frac{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k^H}{\lambda + {\mathbf{r}}_k^H \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k} \right),\\
\hat{\mathbf{p}}_k &= \lambda \hat{\mathbf{p}}_{k-1} + \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k x_k^*,\\
\mathbf{c}_k &= \mathbf{P}_k\hat{\mathbf{p}}_k.
\end{align}

Prove that
$$
\mathbf{c}_k = \mathbf{c}_{k-1} + \frac{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k e_k^*}{\lambda + {\mathbf{r}}_k^H \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k},
$$
where
$e_k = x_k - \mathbf{c}_k^H \mathbf{r}_k$.

---

\begin{align}
\mathbf{c}_k &= \mathbf{P}_k \hat{\mathbf{p}}_k\\
&= \lambda^{-1}\left( \mathbf{P}_{k-1} - \frac{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k^H}{\lambda + {\mathbf{r}}_k^H \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k} \right)
\left(\lambda \hat{\mathbf{p}}_{k-1} + \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k x_k^*\right)\\
&= \mathbf{P}_{k-1}\hat{\mathbf{p}}_{k-1} + \lambda^{-1}\mathbf{P}_{k-1}\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k x_k^* - \frac{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k^H}{\lambda + {\mathbf{r}}_k^H \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k}\hat{\mathbf{p}}_{k-1} - \lambda^{-1} \frac{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k^H}{\lambda + {\mathbf{r}}_k^H \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k}\mathbf{r}_kx_k^*\\
&=\mathbf{c}_{k-1} +\lambda^{-1}\left( \mathbf{P}_{k-1} -
 \frac{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k^H}{\lambda + {\mathbf{r}}_k^H \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k} \right)\mathbf{r}_kx_k^* - \frac{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k^H}{\lambda + {\mathbf{r}}_k^H \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k}\hat{\mathbf{p}}_{k-1}\\
&= \mathbf{c}_{k-1} + \lambda^{-1}\mathbf{P}_k\mathbf{r}_kx_k^* - \frac{\tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k^H}{\lambda + {\mathbf{r}}_k^H \tilde{\mathbf{r}}_k}\hat{\mathbf{p}}_{k-1}\\
\vdots
\end{align}

---

I tried many ways to prove that... but :( failed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard problem in recursive least square, and you can refer to the wiki https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter

Since the denotation is different, and I will provide a proof based on my previous notations.

Considering the following problem 
$$\hat{\mathbf{w}}(t) = \mathop{\arg\min}_{\mathbf{w}\in \mathbb{R}^d}  \sum_{i=1}^t (\prod_{j=i+1}^t \lambda (j))\left[y(i) - \mathbf x(i)^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{w} \right]^2$$
Obviously, if $\lambda(t) = \lambda$ as a constant, then it reduces to your problem. And the recursive least square tells as follows,

> 1. $P(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda(t)}[ P(t-1) - \frac{P(t-1)\mathbf{x}(t)\mathbf{x}(t)^\mathrm{T}P(t-1)}{\lambda(t) + \mathbf{x}(t)^\mathrm{T} P(t-1)\mathbf{x}(t)}]$
> 2. $L(t) = P(t) \mathbf x(t)$
> 3. $\hat{\mathbf{w}}(t) = \hat{\mathbf{w}}(t-1) + L(t)[y(t)-\hat{\mathbf{w}}(t-1)^\mathrm{T}\mathbf x(t)]$

---

Then the proof can be described as follows.
For convenience, let $\Lambda(i,t)=\prod_{j=i+1}^t \lambda (j)$, then the close-form solution of optimization can be calculated as follows
\begin{equation}
\small
\label{close-form}
\hat{\mathbf{w}}(t) = \left[\sum_{i=1}^t \Lambda(i,t) \mathbf x(i)\mathbf x(i)^\mathrm{T}  \right]^{-1} \left[\sum_{i=1}^t \Lambda(i,t) \mathbf x(i)y(i) \right]
\end{equation}

Denote $\bar{R}(t) = \sum_{k=1}^t \Lambda(i,t) \mathbf x(t)\mathbf x(t)^\mathrm{T}$, obviously
\begin{equation}
\bar{R}(t) = \lambda(t)\bar{R}(t-1) + \mathbf x(t)\mathbf x(t)^\mathrm{T}
\end{equation}
Then the solution in above close-form solution can be rewritten into the following form:
\begin{equation*}
\label{proof-close-form}
\begin{split}
\hat{\mathbf{w}}(t) &= \bar{R}^{-1}(t)\left[\lambda(t) \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} \Lambda(i,t-1) \mathbf x(i)y(i) + \mathbf x(t)y(t)\right]\\
&= \bar{R}^{-1}(t)\left[ \lambda(t)\bar{R}(t-1)\hat{\mathbf{w}}(t-1) + \mathbf x(t)y(t)\right]\\
&= \bar{R}^{-1}(t)\left[ (\bar{R}(t) - \mathbf x(t)\mathbf x(t)^\mathrm{T}) \hat{\mathbf{w}}(t-1) + \mathbf x(t)y(t)\right]\\
&= \hat{\mathbf{w}}(t-1) + \bar{R}^{-1}(t)\mathbf x(t)\left[y(t) - \mathbf x(t)^\mathrm{T} \hat{\mathbf{w}}(t-1))\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now, we introduce  $P(t) =  \bar{R}^{-1}(t)$ and then apply rank-1 update rule to above, this gives
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
P(t) & =  \frac{1}{\lambda(t)}P(t-1)- \frac{1}{\lambda(t)}P(t-1)\mathbf{x}(t) \\
& \cdot \left[\frac{1}{\lambda(t)}\mathbf{x}(t)^\mathrm{T}P(t-1)\mathbf{x}(t) +1\right]^{-1} \frac{1}{\lambda(t)}\mathbf{x}(t)^\mathrm{T}P(t-1)\\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda(t)}\left[ P(t-1) - \frac{P(t-1)\mathbf{x}(t)\mathbf{x}(t)^\mathrm{T}P(t-1)}{\lambda(t) + \mathbf{x}(t)^\mathrm{T} P(t-1)\mathbf{x}(t)}\right]\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Let $L(t) = P(t)\mathbf{x}(t)$, we can obtain the policy described at the first.